# What is the current status of named arguments (named method parameters, keyword arguments) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, ruby-2.0

I have heard that named method arguments will be among the feature improvements in Ruby 2.0. Can someone let me in on their current established syntax in Ruby 2.0?

Comment: There's no established syntax yet. It's still being discussed, at least according to the article Thomas has linked to.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear, because I'm just reading the Ruby 2.0 feature suggestions, and I have one ;)

Comment: Been there, [done that](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7132), we'll see what Matz says to it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update: Here's a [great 6mins screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8Q6Of_mScI) by Peter Cooper on Keyword Arguments in Ruby 2.0.

Old: Have a look at [this blog post about Keyword Arguments in Ruby 2.0](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/) from yesterday.